# On the weak convergence in reflexive Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Consider the following proposition:

**Proposition 1.** Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ that is bounded and has at most one weakly sequentially cluster point $x$. Then $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to $x$.

We have known that Proposition 1 is a **direct corollary** of the following theorems and proposition:

**Theorem 1. (Kakutani)** Let $X$ be a Banach space. Then $X$ is reflexive if and only if
$$
B_X=\{x\in X: \|x\|\leq 1\}
$$ 
is compact in the weak topology $\sigma(X, X^*)$.

**Theorem 2. (Eberline-Smulian)** Let $X$ be a Banach space. Then the following statements are equivalent:

(i) $B_X$ is weakly compact;

(ii) $B_X$ is sequentially weakly compact.

**Proposition 2.** Let $C$ be a sequentially compact subset of a Hausdorff space $X$
and suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $C$ that admits a unique sequential cluster point $x$.
Then $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$.

**I woulk like to ask where we can find the reference of Proposition 1**.

Thank you for all comments and helping.

Comment: In Exercise 3.176 of Fabian, you could get some remarks for your question